# Does Silencer's ultimate reveal Riki?

Tags: dota-2

I haven't had a successful opportunity to try and cast Silencer's global silence in a game with an enemy Riki yet but I have silenced in an area with Death Prophet where I managed to hit Riki and it revealed him by silencing his invisibility, would Silencer's ultimate not then reveal him too? Couldn't find sufficient data debunking this anywhere yet and an old friend who played Dota 1 said it doesn't work.

Comment: good question, for yhe time being my guestimate is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Riki will be revealed in this case.

All silences reveal Riki, as well as truesight or if he attacks. Riki is the only invis hero to be revealed by silence.

From memory (going back a few years), Riki wasn't revealed in Dota1 by silence effects, so your friend is correct as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure silences have always revealed Riki in ultimate form. For the vast majority of scenarios, Dota2 has simply copied Dota1 functionality, even if it's funny.

Comment: Appears you are right, I'm either imagining it or I was a scrub back then.  Probably both.